# Azure - Get Log Analtycis query trough Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to create a web activity in ADF to run a query in log analytics and have this result as output in ADF (Data Factory).

Is it possible ?

I tried to generate a ADD token and passed it to web Activity:
[image]

and the url that I'm using is: [https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/[Workspace](https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/%5BWorkspace) ID]/query

but I got an error:

[image]

I already gave access to app like reader and data access to Log Analytics.

Can anyone please help me in achieving this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to get the bearer token and then pass that bearer token when you make the actual call to log analytics API , its going to be two step workflow . I use to test the thing in curl or postman and once it succeed there I try to implement in ADF .

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/api/access-api#client-credentials-flow